# How to install mu and mu4e with GUI Emacs

Tags: osx, mu4e

I've been using [this guide](http://cachestocaches.com/2017/3/complete-guide-email-emacs-using-mu-and-/) to set up email in Emacs on `macOS`. I managed the `offlineimap` connection and replication into a `Maildir`. I installed `mu` with `brew install mu`:

```
$ which mu
/usr/local/bin/mu
```

But I cannot find anything in the Emacs `site-lisp` to launch `mu4e`:

$ ls /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/
ls: /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/: No such file or directory

But [the website](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/) suggests that `mu4e` is installed:

> mu includes an emacs-based e-mail client (mu4e)

I tried [building from git](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Installation.html) and [using brew in this way](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/16504):

```
EMACS=$(which emacs) brew install mu --with-emacs --HEAD
```

and in both cases I get:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gmime-3.0) were not met:

No package 'gmime-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GMIME_CFLAGS
and GMIME_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

and this package is not in brew:

```
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Furthermore, on my home computer the command `EMACS=$(which emacs) brew install mu --with-emacs --HEAD` reinstalls `emacs` with `brew`, despite it being already installed.

Another attempt is to install `mu`, then just copy the `mu4e` files to `site-lisp`:

```
brew install mu
git clone git://github.com/djcb/mu.git
mkdir /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/
cp -r mu4e /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/
```

and adding this in ~/.emacs:

```
(require 'mu4e)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e")
```

But I get the error `Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, mu4e-meta`. And still, `M-x mu4e` doesn't work.

How can I install `mu4e`?

Comment: And your .emacs configuration? is mu4e required? is the mail path loaded? can you please  provide a link to your config? or paste the relevant par there?

Comment: I had not added `(require 'mu4e)`, which I now updated the question with. Those two lines are the relevant part of `.emacs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get elisp files installed together with `mu` using `brew` in OSX, you need to run:

```
brew install mu
```

The available arguments to mu install is shown with `brew info mu`.

You can get the list of all installed files with `brew ls --verbose mu`.
At the moment, the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/mu/1.0/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e/` gets symlinked to `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e`.

The mu configuration in your emacs init file needs to first call add-to-list pointing to the directory where mu4e files are, followed by the form `(require mu4e)` and all other variable settings:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e")
(require 'mu4e)
 ...
```

If mu4e fails to start even after require'ing it, you should try adding `(setq mu4e-mu-binary "/usr/local/bin/mu")`. mu4e has tons more variables you can set to get the behavior you want.

Comment: I ran that, and got `ls: /usr/local/Cellar/mu/1.0/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e/: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Find out where the files are with `brew ls --verbose mu`

Comment: You need to `add-to-list` the relavant directory *before* you `require`.

Comment: These changes worked: `brew install mu --wtih-emacs` and `add-to-list` before `require`! I then configured `mu4e` with this [minimal configuration](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Minimal-configuration.html). Can you include those changes so I accept the answer?

Comment: Changes included.

Comment: The option `--with-emacs` fails. [`mu` comes with `mu4e`](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Installation.html), so you can install with `brew install mu` and verify that `mu4e` is installed if `brew ls --verbose mu>` lists directories with `emacs/site-lisp`.

Answer (score 2):

I just got mu with mu4e installed on Mojave.   Here are links to the problems associated with doing so on a Mac:

Cf for an explanation of the problem & hurdles:

1. "installing mu and mu4e with homebrew with emacs from emacsforosx"
   https://blog.danielgempesaw.com/post/43467552978/installing-mu-and-mu4e-with-homebrew-with-emacs
2. "A COMPLETE GUIDE TO EMAIL IN EMACS USING MU AND MU4E"
   http://cachestocaches.com/2017/3/complete-guide-email-emacs-using-mu-and-/

And, here is what worked for me:

1. In order to modify /usr/bin/emacs to prevent Homebrew from dropping the co-install of "mu4e", I had to disable the System Integrity Process: reboot + Cmd+R for recovery mode + 'Utilities' > Terminal & 
   `csrutil status` 
   && 
   `csrutil disable`
   &&
   `reboot` (to exit recovery mode)
2. Then, after moving /usr/bin/emacs to /usr/bin/emacs.bak, I symlinked a version of Emacs > 23.6 (I think that's the minimum version required by Homebrew to trigger an install of 'mu4e' along with mu) into /usr/bin (which is where Homebrew checks to see which version of Emacs is installed).  See the above linked webpages for details.
3. Symlink an installed Emacs > 23.6 into /usr/bin

➜ ✗ sudo ln -s /Applications/Emacs1.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs /usr/bin/emacs

4. Verify the symlink:

➜ ✗ ls -l /usr/bin/emacs
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  45 Apr 12 17:04 /usr/bin/emacs -> /Applications/Emacs1.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs

5. Install mu w/ mu4e (Already had Emacs-27.0.90 installed.)

➜ ✗ brew install mu --HEAD

This is what I had for mu & mu4e after the install:

➜ ✗ ls /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e

➜ ✗ ls -l /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e

6. Symlink 'mu' to /usr/local/bin

➜ ✗ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mu/HEAD-e9fb70e_1/bin/mu /usr/local/bin/

7. Verify the symlink.

➜ ✗ ls -l /usr/local/bin/mu
/usr/local/bin/mu -> /usr/local/Cellar/mu/HEAD-e9fb70e_1/bin/mu

8. Verify the 'mu' symlink
   ➜ ✗ which mu
   /usr/local/bin/mu
9. Test 'mu' command-line use

➜ ✗ mu --version 
mu (mail indexer/searcher) version 1.3.10
Copyright (C) 2008-2020 Dirk-Jan C. Binnema
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html.

That's as far as I've gone with mu+mu4e.  I haven't yet tested it in Emacs.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The advice of running `brew ls mu` is a great start but it'll get you a path that has a version number in it. E. g., `[snip]/1.x.x/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e`. I am guessing this link goes bad if the version number changes after an update. That is why we need a symlink.

It seems that the symlink used to be at `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e` but as many comments point out--that is no longer true. It is probably because the output to `brew --prefix` has changed from `/usr/local`. The symlink can always be reliably found by `echo $(brew --prefix)/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e`. Try,

```
ls $(brew --prefix)/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e
```

And you should see the elisp files.