# Mu fails to install and Mu4e fails to start: /usr/local/opt/emacs not present or broken

Tags: osx, mu4e

I upgraded `mu` and `emacs` and now `mu4e` stopped working.

I removed Emacs with:

```
brew uninstall --force emacs
brew uninstall --force homebrew/cask/emacs
```

and `mu` with:

```
brew uninstall mu
```

Then I installed `emacs` again with:

```
$ brew install homebrew/cask/emacs
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Downloading https://emacsformacosx.com/emacs-builds/Emacs-28.1-4-universal.dmg
==> Downloading from https://emacsformacosx.com/download/emacs-builds/Emacs-28.1-4-universal.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Installing Cask emacs
==> Moving App 'Emacs.app' to '/Applications/Emacs.app'
==> Linking Binary 'Emacs' to '/usr/local/bin/emacs'
==> Linking Binary 'ebrowse' to '/usr/local/bin/ebrowse'
==> Linking Binary 'emacsclient' to '/usr/local/bin/emacsclient'
==> Linking Binary 'etags' to '/usr/local/bin/etags'
==> Linking Manpage 'ebrowse.1.gz' to '/usr/local/share/man/man1/ebrowse.1.gz'
==> Linking Manpage 'emacs.1.gz' to '/usr/local/share/man/man1/emacs.1.gz'
==> Linking Manpage 'emacsclient.1.gz' to '/usr/local/share/man/man1/emacsclient.1.gz'
==> Linking Manpage 'etags.1.gz' to '/usr/local/share/man/man1/etags.1.gz'
  emacs was successfully installed!
```

and `mu` with:

```
$ brew install mu
Warning: You are using macOS 10.14.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

==> Downloading https://github.com/djcb/mu/releases/download/v1.8.7/mu-1.8.7.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/mmorin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c9448438bd8aad02695c3987230eb7478f831fa4e0ec02ba2abe5f7949a793e5--mu-1.8.7.tar.xz
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1.

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/emacs not present or broken
Please reinstall emacs. Sorry :(
```

I also upgraded command-line tools with:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

but I still see that message about an old version of command-line tools.

`mu` complains that `/usr/local/opt/emacs` is missing, which it is.

Following [a question from a few years ago](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46156/how-to-install-mu-and-mu4e-with-gui-emacs/46171#46171), I also tried:

```
EMACS=$(which emacs) brew install mu --HEAD
```

and I get the same error.

When I launch Emacs, I see:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘...’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, mu4e

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace. Disable showing Disable logging
```

This last error usually happens when `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e/` is missing, but I checked that it does exist on my system:

```
$ ls /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e/
Makefile.am TODO        fdl.texi    mu4e-about.org  mu4e-meta.el.in mu4e.texi
```

The last thing I could try, but which is troublesome for me at the moment, is to reinstall and upgrade the OS because Brew and Apple no longer support 10.14.

Before reinstalling, is there anything else I could try to make `mu` and `mu4e` work on Emacs?

### update

I reinstalled Emacs and it is now at the latest version:

```
$ brew upgrade --cask emacs
Warning: Not upgrading emacs, the latest version is already installed
```

When I install `mu`, I see that it installs emacs again:

```
==> Installing mu dependency: emacs
...
==> ./configure --enable-locallisppath=/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp --infodir=/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/28.1/share/info/emacs --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/28.1 --with-gnutls --without-x 
==> make                                
==> make install
==> emacs cask is installed, skipping link.
Error: Failed to install service files
  /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/28.1: 4,093 files, 110.1MB, built in 5 minutes 35 seconds
```

So maybe that is the issue: how can I install a single version of emacs for the GUI and the command-line?

Comment: This question is entirely about brew rather than Emacs. You might have better luck asking people who focus on brew questions instead.

Comment: Thanks @db48x . I asked at Apple.SE: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444415/mu-fails-to-install-and-mu4e-fails-to-start-usr-local-opt-emacs-not-present-or

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to Apple.StackExchange.com